# How to use React Navigation universal links with path parameters on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I have the following domain: `https://demoproject.com`

I would like to link all URL-s with `/demo` path parameter with my React Native application on Android so that for example URL `https://demoproject.com/demo?a=1&b=2` will be linked, but any other URL with same domain, but different path parameters will be excluded.

Right now I am using React Navigation 5 like this:

```
const linking = {
    prefixes: ['https://demoproject.com'],
    config: {
      DemoScreen: {
          path: '/demo/*'
      }
    }
};
<NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="https" />
      <data android:host="demoproject.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

Linking itself is working fine, but the problem is that all URL-s with prefix `https://demoproject.com` are being linked while I only want URL-s with `/demo` path parameter to be linked.

I have tried:

- `<data android:host="demoproject.com/demo" />` - none of the URL-s are linked
- `prefixes: ['https://demoproject.com/demo']` - all of the URL-s with `https://demoproject.com` domain are linked

Any ideas how to solve this or what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be defined in the IntentFilter with `pathPrefix` or `pathPattern`:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="https" />
      <data android:host="demoproject.com" android:pathPrefix="/demo/" />
</intent-filter>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element#path

Comment: android:pathPrefix nailed it